# How to Control VertexLabels

Tags: graphs-and-networks

Is there a way to control the labels of nodes in a graph - that is, suppressing the names of some nodes but showing the names of other nodes? For example, consider the graph:

```
edges = {N1 -> N2, N2 -> N3, N3 -> N4, N4 -> N5, N6 -> N2, N6 -> N3, 
  N6 -> N4, N1 -> N8, N2 -> N8, N4 -> N8, N7 -> N8, N9 -> N7, N9 -> N8}
g = Graph[edges, VertexLabels -> Automatic]
```

Setting VertexLabels->None suppresses the names of all nodes. How can I control this such that ALL nodes in the graph are without labels, **except** for those whose names I specify to be labeled? For instance, in the above graph suppose I want only nodes N1 and N6 to be labeled but all the other nodes to not be labeled?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Graph[edges, VertexLabels -> {N1 | N6 -> "Name"}]
```

or

```
Graph[edges, VertexLabels -> {N1 | N6 -> Automatic}]
```

[image]

To attach arbitrary labels to nodes 1 and 6, say, `"label 1"` and `"label 2"`, use

```
Graph[edges, 
 VertexLabels -> Thread[{N1, N6} -> {"label 1", "label 6"}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Wonderful; once again many thanks kglr!!

Comment: @PRG, my pleasure.